# Why does mysql client ask me for user to be introduced as <username@hostname>

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

when I connect to a mysql database in the following way an error is printed asking me to introduce user as username@hostname:
`mysql -h <hostname> -u<user_name> -P 3306 -p<password>`

Introducing it in that other way it works:
`mysql -h <hostname> -u<user_name>@<hostname> -P 3306 -p<password>`

However, my workmates are able to connect to the database putting only the user, since you are indicating the host with option -h

Why?
PD:
mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.40, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

I attach error shown
[image]

Comment: I've been using MySQL for over 20 years, but I've never seen it require the username to be in the format "<user_name>@<hostname>". Can you edit your post and include the exact error message it printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error 9002 is specific to Microsoft Azure, not plain MySQL.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/single-server/quickstart-create-mysql-server-database-using-azure-portal#connect-to-azure-database-for-mysql-server-using-mysql-command-line-client

> For Azure Database for MySQL, you need to add `@<servername>` to the admin user name, as shown here:
>
> ```
> mysql --host=mydemoserver.mysql.database.azure.com --user=myadmin@mydemoserver -p
> ```

I don't use Azure, and I don't know why they have this requirement. I suggest you ask their [technical support](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/).